# How to Match The Inner Possible Result With Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, string, nested

I have a regular expression to match anything between { and } in my string.

> "/{.*}/"

Couldn't be simpler.  The problem arises when I have a single line with multiple matches.  So if I have a line like this:

> this is my {string}, it doesn't {work} correctly

The regex will match

> {string}, it doesn't {work}

rather than

> {string}

How do I get it to just match the first result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Question-mark means "non-greedy"

```
"/{.*?}/"
```

Comment: i don't know if you'll aver have nested braces but this will not return desired results if they are there. for {aaa{bbb}ccc} it will return {aaa{bbb}.

Comment: This works as expected, although Victor's point is a good one.  Possibly a topic for another post...

Answer (score 4):

Use a character class that includes everything except a right bracket:

```
/{[^}]+}/
```

Comment: This is a better habit than the accepted answer.  For a more complex regular expression, this will not fall prey to catastrophic backtracking.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 2):

this will work with single nested braces with only a depth of one: `{(({.*?})*|.*?)*}`

I'm not sure how to get infinite depth or if it's even possible with regex

Answer (score 1):

Default behaviour is greedy matching, i.e. first { to last }. Use lazy matching by the ? after your *.,

```
/{.*?}/
```

or even rather than * use "not a }"

```
/{[^}]*}/
```